# LoadSelect creating unexpected query

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I'm attempting to load a date filtered list of objects that have a reference via LoadSelect. However when the query is generated to load the references it is not constructed properly and I receive a "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." error

Here are the POCO classes

```cs
[Alias("Users")]
 public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CompletedDate { get; set; }

        [Reference]
        public Account Account { get; set; }

        [References(typeof(Account))]
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    }

[Alias("Accounts")]
public class Account
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }   
    }
```

With the following query

```cs
var query = db.From<User>()
    .Where(x => x.CreatedDate > fromDate)
    .And(x => x.CreatedDate < toDate);

var result = db.LoadSelect(query);
```

The dialect is SqlServer2016Dialect, the date fields are datetimeoffset(7)

This produces the following sql queries

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT "Id", "Name", "CreatedDate", "ModifiedDate", "CompletedDate", "AccountId" 
FROM "Users"
WHERE ("CreatedDate" > @0) AND ("CreatedDate" < @1)',N'@0 datetimeoffset(7),@1 datetimeoffset(7)',@0='2017-08-27 00:00:00 +10:00',@1='2019-04-19 23:59:59 +10:00'
```

And this is the query that is attempting to load the references

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT "Id", "Title" FROM "Accounts" WHERE "Id" IN (SELECT "Users"."AccountId" 
FROM "Users"
WHERE ("CreatedDate" > ''27/08/2017 00:00:00 +10:00'') AND ("CreatedDate" < ''19/04/2019 23:59:59 +10:00''))',N'@0 datetimeoffset(7),@1 datetimeoffset(7)',@0='2017-08-27 00:00:00 +10:00',@1='2019-04-19 23:59:59 +10:00'
```

Running this query will result is a "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

If I take the where command off this query it works as expected.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you defining `fromDate` and `toDate` in the query generation?